# Double integration identity

Tags: integration, partial-derivative

I came across the following identity, without any explanation or proof:

$$\int_{t_0}^{t_*}dt\int_{t}^Tdx\frac{\partial f(t,x)}{\partial t}=\int_{t_0}^{t_*}dtf(t,t)+\int_{t_*}^Tdxf(t,x)-\int_{t_0}^Tdxf(t,x).$$

I have been trying to find a "proof" (does not need to be entirely rigorous) for quite some time now but can't seem to find an explanation.
The function $f$ is a well-behaving continuous function.

Any tips/help is welcome!

Comment: Use by-parts integration may be, it will come.

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd integrals in your RHS make no sense. The $t$ in them should be $t_0.$

Comment: Integration by parts is irrelevant. Hint (Chasles+Fubini): $$\iint_{t_0<t<t_*,\;t<x<T}=F(t_0)-F(t_*)$$ where
$$F(a)=\iint_{a<x<T,\;a<t<x}.$$

Comment: @AnneBauval That's what I have been scratching my head for... But the identity as presented in my question is exactly how I found it in the book by B. Baaquie

Comment: Never heard of this Mr Baaquie but I am absolutely sure this is a typo. If you follow my hint, you will find the RHS with the correction I indicated for this typo (and with the letter $x$ instead of the letter $t$ for the integration variable in the first integral of the RHS, but this does not matter).

Comment: Knowing Anne's correction, you should be able to find a simple counterexample to the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @AnneBauval 's comment and drawing a graphical representation of the integration region, I was able to come up with the following derivation:

$$\int_{t_0}^{t_*}dt\int_t^Tdx\frac{\partial f(t,x)}{t}=\int_{t_0}^Tdx\int_{t_0}^xdt\frac{\partial f(t,x)}{t}-\int_{t_*}^Tdx\int_{t_*}^xdt\frac{\partial f(t,x)}{t}$$
By the fundamental theorem of calculus
$$=\int_{t_0}^Tdx[f(x,x)-f(t_0,x)]- \int_{t_*}^Tdx[f(x,x)-f(t_*,x)]$$
Collecting $f(x,x)$ yields
$$=\int_{t_0}^{t_*}dxf(x,x)-\int_{t_0}^Tdxf(t_0,x)+\int_{t_*}^Tdx f(t_*,x)$$

Such as was mentioned in the comments, the identity contains a typo.